# Geometrical interpretation of modulus of a cross product

Tags: vectors

Context: this question is set as an A-level question.

When we want to interpret modulus of a cross product, there are usually two scenarios:

1. For the case where $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ are position vectors, $|\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b}|$ is area of a parallelogram with $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ as adjacent sides;
2. For the case where $\mathbf{a}$ is a unit vector, we can also see $|\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b}|$ as shortest distance from $B$ to $OA$.

However I saw this one today: $\left|\vec{OA}\times \dfrac{\vec{AN}}{|\vec{AN}|}\right|$. I believe context of $A$ and $N$ does not matter, and $O$ is the origin. I certainly cannot see this is perpendicular distance from $A$ to $AN$, since we have to show that this is equal to some nonzero value.

Sorry for the bad formatting; apart from the \vv command I am not sure how to represent a vector here.

Comment: You can use \vec to draw the vector arrows.

Comment: Does it help to note that $\frac{\vec{AN}}{|\vec{AN}|}$ is a unit vector?

Comment: @Spencer thanks for the heads up and edit.

Comment: @StinkingBishop that i noticed, but as i said i dont think it should mean perpendicular distance from A to AN.

Comment: In physics, the modulus of the cross product might represent torque.

Answer (score 1):

$$|\vec a \times \vec b|= ab \sin \theta$$

1-$|\vec a \times \vec b|$ is the area of parallelogram whose adjacent  sides are represented
by $\vec a$ and $\vec b$.

2-$|\vec a \times \vec b|$ is twice the area of whose adjacent sides are represented
by $\vec a$ and $\vec b$.

3- $|\vec a \times \vec b|$ area of parallelogram whose adjacent  sides are represented
by $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ is twice the area of infinitely many quadrilaterals whose diagonals are $\vec a$ and $\vec b$.

Here, $\vec a, \vec b$ are not position vectors the are absolute vectors.

Edit:

To OP:
$$\left |\vec OA \times \frac{\vec ON}{|\vec ON |}\right|$$ is the length  of perpendicular projection of $\vec OA$ perpendicular to $\vec ON$ wgich is the length of $\vec AN$

Comment: yeah i understand all these, but the issue here is that $\vec{AN}$ here is not a position vector.

Comment: @Kenny Wong  Thanks, you may like my edit.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution after some searching. apparently it will be like (1) as posted, but using $A$ as point of reference here, so the answer is perpendicular distance from $O$ to $AN$.